# The Metathesis in "scope" vs "to show"

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

I would like to hear some ideas that can explain Greek *[σκέπτομαι](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%AD%CF%80%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B9#Ancient_Greek), σκοπός "watcher, look-out, spy, mark, goal"

> from Proto-Indo-European *skep-ye-, from a metathesis of *speḱ-.
>
> Cognate to Latin speciō (“I see”).

... especially the metathesis.

German *schauen* "to watch", En. "to [show](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/show)" are PGmc *skawwōną (“to look, see”), IE *(s)kewh₁-(“to heed, look, feel, take note of”). *(s)kewh₁- could conceivably relate to [*h2ew-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82ew-#Proto-Indo-European) (Def. 2 "to perceive"). Could these have, for example, influenced the metathesis?

Comment: I just want to say ‘methatesis’ is awesome :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite possibly!

There was definitely a Proto-Greek form **skow-os* < **sk-o-wh₁-os* meaning something like "watching" or "overseeing"; it didn't survive on its own, but is attested in compounds like *thyo-sko(w)ós* "haruspex" (+ *thy-* "sacrifice").

When you have **skow-os* "watching" next to **spok-os* "watcher", a transformation into *skop-os* isn't at all implausible. This then spread to other forms of the same root, giving *skep-sis*, *skop-éō*, and so on.

Comment: A switcheroo in PIE is is also possible unless treating the roots as unrelated. Anyway, great insight, thank you.

Comment: Mainstream opinion traces *spy/spähen* to \*SPEK’, but *show/schauen* to \*(S)KOU.  The latter also yields *ακου(σ)ω & κοεω* in Greek and *caveo* in Latin.